# Must declare the scalar variable "@@procid"

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I'm pretty new to SQL Server. I'm trying to create a simple procedure to get the name of the current procedure name for debugging purpose.

This is the code.

```
-- ======================================================================
-- Create Stored Procedure Template for Azure SQL Data Warehouse Database
-- ======================================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [stg].[test_procid]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @objectname VARCHAR(200);
    SET @objectname = QUOTENAME(object_schema_name(@@procid)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(object_name(@@procid));
END
GO
```

When I execute this code, I get this error.

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@@procid".

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help

Update:
Thanks @Larnu and @David. I'm using Azure SQL Data Warehouse and I think that is the reason. I want this information to be passed on to another procedure in a generic way than hardcoding the procedure name.

Is there any way to do it in Azure Data Warehouse?

Comment: It works when running in SQL Management studio locally.  The @@ProcID may not be valid in azure db because in SQL 2012 it works locally

Comment: As per the [documentation](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/procid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), it is not available in Azure Data Warehouse.

Comment: FYI, SCHEMA_NAME and OBJECT_NAME might be a replacement you could use.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. I think that is the reason. I what this information to be passed on to  another procedure in a generic way than hardcoding the procedure name. Is there any way to do it in Azure Data Warehouse.

Comment: @BKM hi, try using @@spid i think it’s can be work because hard coded the stored procedures name are soo long :(

Comment: @BKM You should accept David's answer as the correct one to your initial question. You should then ask your updated question about whether there is a way to achieve this in Azure SQL Data Warehouse as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@@procid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/procid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is not supported on Azure SQL Data Warehouse.  This is documented.

It works fine on Azure SQL Database.

Comment: yes  @@PROCID  is NOT supported  for azure synapse Dedicated SQL pool however the doc you refer to fails to post advised alternative which is the point of the OP question

Answer (score 1):

I think you can test the relevant query on beginning off your stored procedure :

```
select object_name(objectid) from sys.dm_Exec_requests ec cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec.sql_handle) where session_id=@@spid
```

@@spid : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/spid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Update :

```
select object_name(objectid) from sys.dm_Exec_requests AS EC cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(EC.sql_handle) where session_id=@@spid
```

Comment: When I try to execute this sql I get this error `Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Parse error at line: 22, column: 92: Incorrect syntax near 'ec'.`

Comment: Your are executing query in SSMS ?

Comment: @BKM you can try by adding AS EC (the query updated) ?

Comment: I'm testing the SQL in SSMS and the updated SQl gave the same error. It is complaining about the "ec" at `sys.dm_exec_sql_text(EC.sql_handle)`

Comment: Yes related to the documentation cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sql-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 was not supported on Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Comment: As I wrote in my answer at the MSDN forum, this will work since both `sys.dm_Exec_requests` and `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` not supported in Azure Data Warehouse.

Comment: I wrote a short blog with a trick, but as much as I know, it is not allowed to publish links to blogs here.I did answer the same question you posted on MSDN and I added there the link to blog as well.